# update table with one query

Tags: codeigniter, sql-update

for example i have one table about amount of money and the amount can increase or decrease .
the table currency_unit is :

```
id = 1
name = dollar
amount = 1000
```

the amount of update is :

```
$change = 5000;
```

for updating the table i have to write two query the first get data from table and the second update that with new data.

i use query builder class

the controller is :

```
$base = $this->base_model->get_data('currency_unit' , 'amount' , array('id'=> 1));
$data['amount'] = $base->amount + $change; // 1000 + 5000 = 6000
$this->base_model->update_data('currency_unit' , $data , array('id'=> 1));
```

the model is :

```
function get_data($table , $select , $where){
$this->db->select($select);
$this->db->where($where);
$result = $this->db->get($table);
return $result->row();
}
function update_data($table , $data , $where){
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->update($table , $data);
}
```

Is there any way i update amount with one query not two query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hope it will work

```
$this->db->set('amount', 'amount+500', FALSE);
```

OR

```
$this->db->set('amount', 'amount+'.$change, FALSE);

$this->db->where('id', 1);
$this->db->update('currency_unit');
```